# how must my javascript look like to run at the end of my ASP.NET page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

this code is put at the top of my asp.net page:

```
function Test(HtmlDocument) 
{ 
}
```

How can I execute this javascript function at the end of my page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is using windows.onload. The event can be used to perform some task as soon as the page finishes loading. Here is an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function my_code(){
alert(" Alert inside my_code function");
}

window.onload=my_code();
</script>
```

Comment: When I try to pass the my_code() function a parameter like window.onload=my_code(this) "this" should be the document then I get those errors:A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll

Comment: could you check if it throws an exception  without this parameter

Comment: without params its ok but the onload event does not occur when the site was loaded but when the is about to load... that does not help.

Comment: The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images and sub-frames have finished loading. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload

Comment: Well then its not working on IE 8.0 because I used the onload and it did not find the control because it wasnt yet rendered to html. Seems a IE problem?

Answer (score 3):

Just invoke the function in `<script>` tags immediately before the `</body>` tag.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- snip -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- snip -->

        <script>
            Test(document);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: its an asp.net page which has no body tag see my question title.

Comment: You're talking about a `.aspx` file?

Answer (score 2):

Simply put

```
<script>Test(document);</script>
```

In the end of your html

Answer (score 0):

Or you can put the function at the bottom of the code without the function declaration

```
<script>
Your javascript code here
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to drop a script manager on the page (anywhere within the body of the page) then put something like this on the page ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
           // do your thing
    });
</script>
```

That executes client side when the document has finished loading.